# Can you confirm the SDK SOS version to use?

Tags: mobilesdk

We have opened leticket 22464515 with Salesforce Support because of the bug encountered in the Android General Company mobile app that crashes the app. After analysis, we found that this bug in the SDK SOS version occurring on Android phones version 8.1.0 ,.

As you say it is important because it's buggy in the web with a crash of the mobile app SG.

To help us fix the problem, we need to specify the SDK SOS version to use, and tell us if there are any potential impacts related to this upgrade.

Can you confirm the SDK SOS version to use?

Answer (score 0):

SOS is a different product than the Mobile SDK.  You are post issues for SOS here: https://github.com/forcedotcom/ServiceSDK-Android